# Remove surface from graphic

Tags: plotting, graphics, geography

How to remove surface from the following graphic?

I need only `Mesh`, (black lines).

```
ListPlot3D[
GeoElevationData[
GeoBoundingBox[
GeoDisk[Entity["Mountain", "MountEverest"], 
5 Quantity[1, "Miles"]]]], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
Mesh -> 30,Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

and why doesn's  work `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`?

```
ListPlot3D[
GeoElevationData[
GeoBoundingBox[
GeoDisk[Entity["Mountain", "MountEverest"], 
5 Quantity[1, "Miles"]]]], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
Mesh -> 30,Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

Comment: For the styling issue try adding the option `PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]`

Comment: @Sascha, `PlotStyle -> None` is even better for that.

Comment: PlotPoints and  MaxRecursion are not a known options in ListPlot3D see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html on Details and Options